# Review link is missing on beta sites at certain reputation thresholds

Tags: bug, review, beta-sites

The reputation thresholds to access review queues on beta sites constantly change - not an issue in itself, but there appears to be a bug around the displaying of the "review" link on these sites.

For example, on Software Recommendations, at 255 reputation I can currently access the Close and Reopen queues. However, I do not have a "review" link in the top bar:

[image]

If I browse to /review manually, I'm allowed to work through the queues, however since the review link is missing some people may not notice they're actually able to review anything.

Since during beta, this kind of activity is important in defining and fine tuning the scope of the site, in addition to bringing attention to potential problems, I feel that this is an important issue.