# Review icon not showing in private beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar, private-beta

The Review icon isn't shown in the top-bar of the newly launched private beta, [Stellar Stack Exchange](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/), even though I have [enough reputation (just 1)](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to review close and reopen votes.

[image]

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220701/review-link-is-missing-on-beta-sites-at-certain-reputation-thresholds, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217206/add-the-review-link-in-the-topbar-on-private-beta-sites-if-i-am-able-to-revi

Comment: The [last one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217206/295232) is [status-completed], so I guess the new topbar design broke it again.

Comment: This relates to the new top bar, so I'm not really sure that it's a dupe. Either way, it's existing and something that needs to be fixed, particularly as the last issue was considered status-completed.

Comment: The team prefers that new bug reports be filed, rather than un-status-completing older ones, so this one isn't a dupe.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog technically, the dupe wasn't status anything... it was just open.

Comment: @Catija Actually, of the two, one's marked [tag:status-completed], and the other one is closed as a dupe of the first

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The question was dupe closed with [this target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202700/review-tab-not-accessible-on-a-private-beta) which is neither status-anything nor duped.

Comment: Looks like this is a regression. There was a change pushed back in March 2017 that "simplified" the check for whether to show the link or not, but also unfortunately dropped [the check for minimum rep required to view *any* queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217206/add-the-review-link-in-the-topbar-on-private-beta-sites-if-i-am-able-to-revi/229935#229935). I'll follow up on this next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back when Stack Overflow Documentation was a thing, its review queue had a rep requirement of 100 points, which caused the icon to appear for a whole lot of people on SO. Unfortunately, at the time the review icon took place of the help icon.

Neither of those is a thing any longer, so the check for minimum reputation is back and the icon should appear correctly on private betas.

Comment: I see review icons on all Meta sites now, even though you need 2k/3k reputation to review there. Was that an intended side effect?

Comment: @Glorfindel Private beta metas or in general?

Comment: On private betas, I can vote to close/reopen so I expect it to be visible there. However, this happens on *all* meta sites, e.g. Travel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymn8M.png

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, that's an issue that has always existed. Basically, if you have the "access review queues" privilege, you're shown the link and we never do any additional checks. This is at least partially for performance reasons - the privilege check is cheap. Meta sites inherit privileges from main, so you have over 500 rep and therefore get to see the link. I think this is minor enough to leave as is.